# What does "embed it into other languages" mean in Wasmer?

Tags: webassembly

On `https://wasmer.io`, it says

```
Use the tools you know and the languages you love. Compile everything to WebAssembly. Run it on any OS or embed it into other languages.
```

What does `embed it into other languages` mean? I have googled but I cannot find any answers related.

Let's say, I have a python program compiled to WebAssembly and I have a Java program to consume it.

1. Can I embed the python program inside the Java program?
2. Is this "embed it into other languages"?
3. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they're saying is that you can embed Wasmer runtime itself in various languages, and then use such embeddings to run WebAssembly compiled from any other source language, as long as it's using [WASI API](https://wasi.dev/) for any input / output.

You can find a list of currently supported embedding targets on their [documentation page](https://docs.wasmer.io/ecosystem/wasmer) or on their [Github account](https://github.com/wasmerio/).

As of time of this writing supported targets include:

- [Rust](https://docs.wasmer.io/integrations/rust)
- [C / C++](https://docs.wasmer.io/integrations/c)
- [Python](https://github.com/wasmerio/python-ext-wasm)
- [Go](https://github.com/wasmerio/go-ext-wasm)
- [PHP](https://github.com/wasmerio/php-ext-wasm)
- [Ruby](https://github.com/wasmerio/ruby-ext-wasm)
- [C#](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/WasmerSharp)
- [R](https://github.com/dirkschumacher/wasmr)
- [Elixir](https://github.com/tessi/wasmex)
- [Postgres](https://github.com/wasmerio/postgres-ext-wasm)

Different targets have different level of readiness, support and documentation, but you can ask more specific questions when you start playing with a specific target.